# Why is Netbeans showing an error in createStatement() for a MySQL database connection?

Tags: java, mysql

There seems to be a problem with `Statement st = conn.createStatement();` Here's my code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

  DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)p1.getModel();
  try{
      Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
      Connection conn=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/product","root","");

      Statement st = conn.createStatement();
      String query="Select*from voltron;";
      ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(query);
      while(rs.next()) {
          String s1=rs.getString("id");
          String s2=rs.getString("product");
          String s3=rs.getString("brand");
          String s4=rs.getString("price");
          String s5=rs.getString("release");

          model.addRow(new Object[]{s1,s2,s3,s4,s5});
      }
      rs.close();;
      st.close();
      conn.close();
  }

  catch (Exception e) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "There is an ERROR");
  }
}
```

Comment: And the problem it shows is...?

Comment: it shows that there is no default createStatement() method,, and show "cannot find symbol", and show to create new method createStatement()

Comment: Please put the *exact* and complete error message into the question.

Comment: cannofind symbol 
symbol: method createStatement()
location:variable conn of type connection

Comment: It's not clear why you're casting the result of `DriverManager.getConnection()` to `Connection`, either, by the way - if you get a compile-time error without the cast, then my guess is that you've got a different `Connection` class somewhere...

Comment: my class name is connection,, I think that why this problem in generating

Comment: Yes, that's the problem...

Comment: Note that if you'd shown a short but *complete* example showing the problem, we'd have found it quicker.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you write `Connection`, the compiler thinks you mean *your* class, rather than `java.sql.Connection`... and your class doesn't have a `createStatement` method.

All you've got to do is specify the class name fully:

```
java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/product","root","");
```

No need for a cast, and the error you're reporting will now go away, as the compiler will be looking for the method in the right class.

Or you could just rename your class, of course - giving your own classes names of related classes within the core Java framework isn't a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Hope This Helps......

```
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventory","root","");
```

Try this one... and use msql-Connector[Here](https://www.versioneye.com/java/mysql:mysql-connector-java/5.1.33)